# Can "to draw" mean "to result in", "to entail"?

Tags: meaning

[thefreedictionary.com](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/draw):
to draw — to bring to a certain condition or action; to lead:
*drawn to despair*
*drew them to resign*
to draw — to bring about deliberately; to provoke:
*to draw enemy fire*
to draw — to evoke as a response; to elicit:
*a performance that drew jeers from the audience*

[britannica.com](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/draw):
to draw — to get a particular response or reaction:
*His speech drew cheers from the crowd.*
*The movie has drawn much criticism/praise from critics.*

[collinsdictionary.com](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/draw):
to draw — to bring about as a result; to bring on; to provoke:
*to draw the enemy's fire*

---

I decided to make up my own examples.
A-variants are from the internet, b-variants are mine.

**(1a)** *Publishing without a license can **result in** a fine or three years in jail*.
**(1b)** *Publishing without a license can **draw** a fine or three years in jail*.

**(2a)** *Budget cuts could **cause** severe social and economic hardship.*
**(2b)** *Budget cuts could **draw** severe social and economic hardship.*

**(3a)** *Such an initiative should also **entail** improved financing opportunities.*
**(3b)** *Such an initiative should also **draw** improved financing opportunities.*

**(4a)** *Such a conflict could even **entail** the use of nuclear weapons.*
**(4b)** *Such a conflict could even **draw** the use of nuclear weapons.*

**(5a)** *Rising sea levels, floods and inundations **entail** heavy consequences for transport infrastructure.*
**(5b)** *Rising sea levels, floods and inundations **draw** heavy consequences for transport infrastructure.*

Which b-variants are correct and which are not and why?

Comment: draw a fine is not a usual idiomatic usage at all and in fact, none of the ones with draw are idiomatic. to draw a reaction to something or from someone (jeers from the crowd)

Comment: Also, there is to draw a check: The check was drawn on the Well Fargo Bank. For example. [US usage]. to draw [an emotion] from somebody or something. His speech drew the ire of the crowd.

Answer (score 2):

If you start off by considering that *'draw'* means *'pull'* then the rest should fall into place.

You draw water from a well - by pulling a rope attached to a bucket.

Your draw fire - by attracting the enemy's attention to make them shoot at you rather than the guy sneaking round the back.

You draw jeers, or cheers, from an audience - by pulling their attention towards your performance.

Once you grasp this, you will see how many of those examples don't work.

You're not really 'pulling' a fine. You're attracting one as a result of your actions, but the fine itself isn't 'pulled'… in effect it's 'pushed', you are compelled to pay it, even though the money travels the opposite direction to the compulsion.

Comment: Excellent answer. The OP needs to *fully* understand an idiomatic usage before attempting to "transplant" it to *similar* (but not *identical*) contexts.